# Android Studio: Difference between BaseAdapter and ArrayAdapter in terms of constructors

Tags: java, android, constructor, adapter

I'm having some confusion understanding how adapters are used. So, the constructor inside a custom ArrayAdapter class is a bit different than the constructor inside a custom BaseAdapter class, and I don't understand how that can happen. So here's a custom ArrayAdapter class constructor;

```
private class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task>{
    TaskAdapter(ArrayList<Task> tasks){
        super(TaskListActivity.this, R.layout.task_list_row,R.id.task_item_name, tasks);
    }
```

And here is a custom BaseAdapter Class constructor;

```
private class FieldsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
ArrayList<String> emails;
ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers;

FieldsAdapter(ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers,ArrayList<String> emails){
this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
this.emails = emails;
}
```

Why is the BaseAdapter class constructor so different? I mean when you save the adapter to a separate object and set the ListView adapter with that object, why does it not need to know all the specific information the TaskAdapter object knows, such as the current context, the layout you want to copy, and the ArrayList you want to populate that layout with, in other words, this `TaskListActivity.this, R.layout.task_list_row,R.id.task_item_name, tasks`? It's all a little confusing for me, the whole purpose of an adapter isn't really making sense anymore. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is that `ArrayAdapter` is a child class of `BaseAdapter`. BaseAdapter gives you more freedom to define data collection type you pass in.
For example, beside `ArrayAdapter`, we have `CursorAdapter`, `SimpleAdapter` which are also extended from `BaseAdapter`.
References:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: I understand that ArrayAdapter is a child class, but I meant why are the constructors so different? I was looking for the difference in terms of constructors

Comment: As I mentioned above `BaseAdapter gives you more freedom to define data collection type you pass in.` ArrayAdapter forces us to follow more strict rule.

Comment: Ohh ok sorry I feel dumb now haha. Thank you!